# Squeak - How do I move a circle?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

In the Squeak Smalltalk environment, I am trying to learn Morphic. There are many, many Morphic classes and I cannot determine the most appropriate one(s) to use for my current application, and I prefer not to invent anything that already exists at this point. Links to relevant code/info would be appreciated. While Pharo might be nicer, I am stuck with Squeak atm.

My question is:
Using Squeak and Morphic, how do I create some sort of canvas, drop it into a movable, scrollable, resizable window, show it on the desktop, drop a circleMorph onto that canvas, and allow the user to grab the circle and move it around on the canvas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a workspace and type:

```
| window canvas circle |
window := SystemWindow new.
canvas := PasteUpMorph new.
window addMorphBack: canvas.
canvas bounds: window bounds.
circle := CircleMorph new.
canvas addMorphCentered: circle.
window openAsIs.
```

This will create a circle on your desktop that you can drag and drop.  Browse the CircleMorph class to find other things you can do.  Also, check out the Documentation section at [www.squeak.org](http://www.squeak.org).  There's a lot of good tutorials there.